# I'm making a simple weather scraper using Node and jQuery, but my GET statements aren't executing as expected. There are no errors in the console

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

Would you please take a look at my GET statements both in app.js and in the index.html's javascript tag where I have the jQuery (bottom of the body tag). I am missing something here...

**app.js**

```
    var express = require('express');
    var weather = require('./public/js/weather.js');

    var app = express();
    var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.send(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
    });

    app.listen(PORT, function() {
        console.log('Express Server Started on port ' + PORT);
    });

    app.get('/location', function(req, res) {

        var city = req.params.city;

        weather(city).then(function (currentWeather) {

            res.json(currentWeather);

        });

    });
```

**weather.js**

```
var request = require('request');


module.exports = function (location) {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        var encodedLocation = encodeURIComponent(location);

        var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + encodedLocation + '&units=imperial&appid=2de143494c0b295cca9337e1e96b00e0';

        if (!location) {

            return reject('No location provided');

        } 

        request({url: url, json: true}, function (error, response, body) {

            if (error) {

                return reject('Unable to fetch weather.');

            } else {

                return resolve('The current temperature in ' + body.name + ' is ' + body.main.temp + ' degrees farenheit.');

            }

        });


    });

}
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Weather Scraper</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

 <!--Bootstrap-->
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <div id="heading" class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 center">

            <h1 class="center">Weather Prediction</h1>
            <p class="lead center">Enter your city for an accurate weather prediction</p>

            <form>

                <div class="form-group">

                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" id="city" placeholder="Eg. London, Venice, Atlanta, Ho Chi Minh City...">

                </div>

                <button id="findMyWeather" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Get Forecast</button>

            </form>

            <div id="success" class="alert alert-success"></div>
            <div id="failure" class="alert alert-danger">Could not find weather data for that city. Please try again.</div>
            <div id="noCity" class="alert alert-danger">Please enter a city</div>


            </div>


        </div>

    </div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#success').hide();
        $('#failure').hide();
        $('#noCity').hide();

        $cityName = $('#city').val();

        $('#findMyWeather').click(function(event) {

            $('#success').hide();
            $('#failure').hide();
            $('#noCity').hide();

            if (typeof $cityName === 'string' && $cityName.length > 0) {

                $.get('/location' + $cityName, function (data) {

                    if (data == "") {

                            $("#failure").fadeIn();

                        } else {

                            $("#success").html(data).fadeIn();
                            $("#success").prepend('<p id="cityTitle" class="lead">'+ $cityName +'</p>');

                        }

                });

            } else {

                $("#noCity").fadeIn();

            }
        });

    });



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you confirm that `body` in weather.js has the format you expect

Comment: If you paste this link into your browser, it's the same URL used in weather.js
 
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Atlanta&units=imperial&appid=2de143494c0b295cca9337e1e96b00e0

I am having a bit of trouble when inspecting the page source. I remember body.name and body.main.temp were working correctly beforehand.

Comment: that doesn't answer the question

Comment: Fair enough, I am in the process of trying to confirm that. I don't remember the page source code that's returned from the api being so short, so I'm having to rewatch some videos...

Comment: There are multiple problems. 1. don't need `form` in this case, and it only stops the code from working anyway. 2. You are not loading `$cityName` when clicking. Your get results in get /locationCityname one word, no param called city ... that's all I've found so far

Comment: 3. in app.js, you'll want to use `req.query.city` not `req.params.city` if you add ?city= to the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**app.js**

```
app.get('/location', function(req, res) {
    var city = req.query.city; // use req.query rather than req.params
    //             ^^^^^
    weather(city).then(function (currentWeather) {
        res.json(currentWeather);
    });
});
```

**index.html**

```
    $('#findMyWeather').click(function(event) {
        $cityName = $('#city').val();
        // ..... load the CURRENT entered city value
        $.get('/location?city=' + $cityName, function (data) {
        //              ^^^^^^ add the query parameter named city
```

Also, remove the `<form>` element from `index.html` - you don't need it, and it only screws up the javascript (you'd have to preventDefault or return false or something in the click event to prevent issues)

Comment: I had this variable:    var $cityName = $('#city').val();     declared outside of 
the click function   $('#findMyWeather').click(function(event) {    so $cityName had no value with the function after I clicked the button. I'm not sure I understand why this would happen... If I declare $cityName outside of the click function, shouldn't it still maintain the same value when I reference it inside the function?

Comment: Thanks for the help!